# Netty send event to sockets

Tags: sockets, events, netty

I am building socket web server with Netty 5.0. I came through WebSocketServer example (https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server). 
But I can't understand how to send events to sockets from separate thread. So I have a thread which each second loads some data from external resource. This is StockThread which receives stock data. After receiving data the thread should send events to sockets. What is best practise to do this?

It am using following approach: inside StockThread I store list of ChannelHandlerContext. After receving data I just call write() method of ChannelHandlerContext. So write() method is called from StockThread. Is it okay or there is more appropriate way for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, *ChannelHandlerContext* is **thread-safe** and can be cached, so this way of usage is completely ok.

See note from "*Netty In Action*" book, that proves my words:

```
You can keep the ChannelHandlerContext for later use, 
such as triggering an event outside the handler methods, 
even from a different Thread.
```